# morphism of locally finite presentation preserves inverse limits

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X_0 \to U_0$ be a morphism locally of finite presentation between schemes.
And let $(U_i)$ be a (directed) inverse system which has the limit $U$.
For $i \ge 0$, set $X_i = X_0 \times_{U_0} U_i$.
Then $X _0 \times_{U_0} U = \lim X_i$?
i.e., is the following diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\lim_i X_i @>>> X_0\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\lim_i U_i @>{q}>> U_0
\end{CD}
Cartesian?

Since inverse limits are limits in the category of schemes, and the fibred products are also limits, I think that this is true for general $f$.

Why do we need the locally finite presentation of $f$?

Comment: Indeed, this is true in any category with limits whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

As remarked in the comments, this is true for general $f$ in any category with limits because [limits commute with limits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/limits+commute+with+limits). The connection between morphisms of locally finite presentation and limits/colimits is that $f:X\to S$ being locally of finite presentation is equivalent to $$\operatorname{colim} \operatorname{Hom}_{Sch/S}(T_i,X) = \operatorname{Hom}_{Sch/S}(\lim T_i,X)$$ for any directed system of affine schemes $T_i$ over $S$ - this is EGA IV proposition 8.14.2, also available as [01ZC](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ZC) at StacksProject.